# I have a DateTime data(like "2021-06-22 17:03:58"),how can i convert it to string(like"17:03”),and then to DateTime again

Tags: c#, datetime, format

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2008, 6, 6, 13, 34, 6);
string v = date.ToString("HH:mm");
DateTime Time = DateTime.Parse(v);
Console.WriteLine(Time);
```

I hope output `13:34,` instead of `12/19/2022 13:34:00`.

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question, then summarise it in the title. Don't ask the question in the title and then provide nothing but code in the question. Spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your code and question:
Since you have a complete time format in date, but want to convert it to a **string** format that only has time and precision, and return the same string to **DateTime** because you only have time and precision in string format. you keep, it causes part of your **data to be lost**, and when you convert it to DatatTime, the time is no longer the same as the time you entered at the beginning of the code, and the date defaults to today's date. and this is **not possible**.

Comment: How can i get a  DateTime type date that only has time and precision from a complete time format in date

Comment: You should state your problem and need in the way it really is so that you can be guided better. Your code is correct, but the only problem is that you want the time again, which is in a string format and only has hours and minutes. Return to the full format again, since you want to convert this string, which does not actually have today's date, to DataTime, if we do not have one for it in the string, it will replace today's date in the output.

Comment: for example,I have a DateTime type date("2021-06-22 17:03:58"),how can I get ("17:03")from it,and it will be DateTime type not other type.The code in my question is that I tried to convert  string, but I don't get the data I want

Comment: You must use this code: string v = date.ToString("HH:mm");And you don't need to convert it to DateTiem again and then display it in the output. I really don't understand why you wrote the third line of your code?

Comment: Because i need a DateTime type not a string type，so，i tried to use DateTime.Parse(v)

Comment: In the first line you wrote, you had the date variable in the DateTime variable, and you don't need to convert it again